First-step lemma for Transfinite Recursion?

Denote $G$ as some function on universal class of sets $V$. Then, the
set $$F: Ord \rightarrow V;\quad F(\alpha) = x$$ where $\alpha \in
> dom(F)$ if and only if there exists some $\alpha$-sequence
$(a)_{\alpha}$(sequence indexed with ordinals in $\alpha$) satisfies:
$(1): \forall \epsilon \in \alpha: a_{\epsilon} = G((a)_{\epsilon})$.
$(2): x = G(a_{\alpha})$
is a function

Original construction:


I interpret the $(a)_{\epsilon}$ as follows: Since $\epsilon \in
> \alpha$, then every elements of $\epsilon$ all belong to $\alpha$. So,
what is meant by $(a)_{\epsilon}$ is we take every element of
$\epsilon$ to address elements in $(a)_{\alpha}$. Like $$\alpha = \{1,
> 2, 3, 4, 5\};\quad \epsilon = \{2, 3, 5\}$$ $$(a)_{\alpha} = \{a_1,
> a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5\};\quad (a)_{\epsilon} = \{a_2, a_3, a_5\}$$ Is
this correct?

He points out that we try a (transfinite) induction proof on this. I only manage to prove the $0$ and $(+1)$-part. Given two sequences with $(a)_{\alpha}$ and $(b)_{\alpha}$ satisfying $(1)$, they must be equal(thus, due to $(2)$, $x$ is the same since $G$ is a function). Now, $(a)_{\alpha} = (b)_{\alpha}$ means specifically that
$$\forall \epsilon \in \alpha: a_{\epsilon} = b_{\epsilon}$$
Let $\epsilon := \emptyset$. Then,
$$a_{\emptyset} = b_{\emptyset} = G(\emptyset)$$
, which completes the base case.
What about the successor step and limit step in Transfinite induction?
If we assume that $a_{\epsilon} = b_{\epsilon}$ then, this "proof" may work:

$a_{\epsilon + 1} = G((a)_{\epsilon + 1})$
$b_{\epsilon + 1} = G((b)_{\epsilon + 1})$
$(a)_{\epsilon + 1}$ contains $a_{\epsilon}$ and $a_{\gamma}$ with
$\gamma \in \epsilon$. Similarly, for $(b)_{\epsilon + 1}$. We do have
$a_{\epsilon} = b_{\epsilon}$. If somehow $a_{\gamma} = b_{\gamma}$
for all $\gamma \in \epsilon$, then $(a)_{\epsilon + 1} =
> (b)_{\epsilon + 1}$. Consequently, $G((a)_{\epsilon + 1}) = G((b)_{\epsilon + 1})$

It is clear that $a_{\epsilon} = b_{\epsilon}$. So, it follows that $G((a)_{\epsilon}) = G((b)_{\epsilon})$. Should $G$ be injective here?

This is trivially easy. The transfinite induction assumes the hypothesis for all indexes smaller than $\eta$. Then, proceeds by considering two cases:

$\eta$ is a successor ordinal. That is, there exists $\epsilon$ with $\eta = \epsilon + 1$. Here, the case $\epsilon$ and all the cases $< \epsilon$ is proved. So, the boxed argument makes sense.

$\eta$ is a limit ordinal. Then, the conclusion follows trivially.


